# Split a PDF apex page into separate PDF pages based on pagenumber

Tags: apex, email, pdf, apex-email-service, repeat

I have an Apex PDF page which I need to email to logged in User. Now when Page number exceeds 10 , I need to send in a separate PDF. Like if I have 15 Pages, PDF1 will have 10 pages , PDF2 will have 5 pages. Can someone help me here?

Please find my PDF page here.

**Apex Page**

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false" doctype="html-4.01-strict" controller="cntl_FormTemplatePrinter" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" cache="false" >

<apex:repeat value="{!lstInteger}" var="int"> 
<apex:repeat value="{!formTransactions}" var="sof">
    <apex:dynamicComponent id="dcx" componentValue="{!ValidTemplate}" />

</apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think you will need an apex code here to chunk the data. Visualforce represents only a view layer of the application.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner unfortunately, I misunderstand your question. Sorry for wrong answer

Comment: @mast0r  Can you please help me in this?